# Hacking Windows Box via Directory Traversal

Tags: web-application, windows, directory-traversal

I am practicing directory traversal attacks and found a vulnerability in a windows XP machine that is running a vulnerable HTTP server that is prone to directory traversal.

I can guess file names and read them successfully but can not execute commands. What are available options to execute code on the box?

I got a copy of /repair/sam however, it was not that much useful since I do not have access to system hives ! The most i could get is the user names of the system.

So any thoughts how to escalate this to get full access?

Hints: only ports 80 and 3389 are open.

Comment: No, it is not !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I should first extract hives from windows/repair/system and use the outputted key when importing hashes to Cain and Abel

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the source of the web app to hopefully find additional vulnerabilities or credentials. For example, you might be able to find a SQL injection by reading the code, or you might be able to find a web.config file containing database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have write access? If so, you can overwrite an existing executable and wait for it to be run. I used this approach in this advisory, which includes a PoC exploit. http://www.pentest.co.uk/documents/ptl-2013-01.html

If you only have read access your options are more limited. You may be able to extract a password from a config file, or extract a password hash and crack it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however,I have read only access.! with respect to cracking SAM hashes, please review my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SAM, then you have the password hashes, too? Have you tried Cain and Abel or John the Ripper to bruteforce the passwords?